# MySQL join that has 2 fields in the join

Tags: mysql, join

I am creating a bookings database for a flight school with a table of times and pilots as a visual day-planner type representation of the flights for the day.  I had it working OK until they obtained an aircraft that needs a co-pilot on occasions.

They have some pilots permanently on the roster (that they want to see on the planner all the time), and some that are used occasionally (that they only want to be there when a booking exists for them that day).  They also wanted to be able to set their own order of the pilots on the planner, so I made an `int_LISTORDER` field in the staff record that set the order in the list, and anyone with a `int_LISTORDER` of 500 and over only appeared when a booking was made for them.  To add a co-pilot to the mix, the booking added a `txt_STAFFNAME2` field in addition to the `txt_STAFFNAME` for the Pilot-in-Command.

I made the following query with the original pilot only version to select all the pilots who have a booking on any particular day (the `$tl_date` variable) that match the list of pilots from the staff listing and get their list-order, and merge that with the list of pilots who have a list-order under 500:

```
        (SELECT DISTINCT tbl_booking_details.txt_STAFFNAME AS txt_PILOT,
                           tbl_staff_details.int_LISTORDER AS int_ORDER
            FROM tbl_booking_details
            INNER JOIN tbl_staff_details
            ON
            tbl_staff_details.txt_PILOTNAME = tbl_booking_details.txt_STAFFNAME
            WHERE tbl_booking_details.date_DATE = '{$tl_date}'
                AND tbl_staff_details.txt_PILOTNAME !='--none--'
                AND tbl_booking_details.txt_COMPLETECODE !='CANCELLED')
            UNION
            (SELECT tbl_staff_details.txt_PILOTNAME AS txt_PILOT,
                    tbl_staff_details.int_LISTORDER AS int_ORDER
            FROM `tbl_staff_details`
            WHERE tbl_staff_details.bool_ISPILOT =1
                AND tbl_staff_details.bool_CURRENT =1
                AND tbl_staff_details.txt_PILOTNAME != '--none--'
                AND tbl_staff_details.int_LISTORDER <500)
            ORDER BY ".STAFF_LIST_ORDER;
```

This query stretched my knowledge of MySQL a bit, so I need to work out how to modify the first part of the query before the `UNION` statement to get the list of pilots (`txt_STAFFNAME`) and co-pilots (`txt_STAFFNAME2`) in 'tbl_booking_detail' and their list-order (`int_LISTORDER`) from 'tbl_staff_detail' who have a booking on that particular day into one table as 'txt_PILOT' and 'int_ORDER'.  Hopefully the names of the fields and values in the WHERE clauses are fairy self explanitory.

Can anyone assist with how to modify this query to meet the new criteria?

regards

Braedon.

Edit:  @bonCodigo

The table details are (minus the many irrelevant fields):

```
tbl_booking_details
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID   |   txt_STAFFNAME | txt_STAFFNAME2 |  date_DATE | txt_COMPLETECODE  | ...
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
475  | Joe A           | Joe B          | 2013-01-14 | CONFIRMED         | ...
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
476  | Joe A           | --none--       | 2013-01-14 | CONFIRMED         | ...
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
476  | Joe C           | Joe A          | 2013-01-14 | CANCELLED         | ...
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
477  | Joe B           | Jane D         | 2013-01-14 | CONFIRMED         | ...
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
478  | Joe E           | Jane D         | 2013-01-14 | CONFIRMED         | ...
------------------------------------------------------------------------------



tbl_staff_details
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID | txt_PILOTNAME | bool_CURRENT| bool_ISPILOT |  int_LISTORDER | ...
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | --none--      | 1           | 1            |  0             | ...
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
2  | Joe A         | 1           | 1            |  5             | ...
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
4  | Joe B         | 1           | 1            |  15            | ...
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
5  | Joe C         | 1           | 1            |  510           | ...
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
6  | Jane D        | 1           | 1            |  20            | ...
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
7  | Joe E         | 1           | 1            |  520           | ...
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Desired Result:

```
--------------------------
| txt_PILOT |  int_ORDER |
--------------------------
| Joe A     |  5         |
--------------------------
| Joe B     | 15         |
--------------------------
| Jane D    | 20         |
--------------------------
| Joe E     | 520        |
--------------------------
```

Comment: Can you provide us with table schema, sample data and expected output please? :)

Comment: Edited question with requested details.

Answer (score 0):

After further research, it seems that I may have over-engineered or complicated my original solution because I may have come at it from the 'wrong angle'.  A complete re-think of the query and using the staff table as the left side of the query instead of the right has come up with the following which seems to work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tbl_staff_details.txt_PILOTNAME AS txt_PILOTNAME,
                tbl_staff_details.int_LISTORDER AS int_LISTORDER
    FROM tbl_staff_details,tbl_booking_details
    WHERE tbl_booking_details.date_DATE = '{$tl_date}'
        AND tbl_booking_details.txt_COMPLETECODE != 'CANCELLED'
        AND tbl_staff_details.txt_PILOTNAME != '--none--'
        AND (tbl_staff_details.txt_PILOTNAME = tbl_booking_details.txt_STAFFNAME
         OR tbl_staff_details.txt_PILOTNAME = tbl_booking_details.txt_STAFFNAME2)
UNION
    SELECT tbl_staff_details.txt_PILOTNAME AS txt_PILOTNAME,
                tbl_staff_details.int_LISTORDER AS int_LISTORDER
    FROM `tbl_staff_details`
    WHERE tbl_staff_details.bool_ISPILOT =1
        AND tbl_staff_details.bool_CURRENT =1
        AND tbl_staff_details.txt_PILOTNAME != '--none--'
        AND tbl_staff_details.int_LISTORDER <500
    ORDER BY int_LISTORDER ASC, txt_PILOTNAME ASC
```

Just using a simple JOIN.  I thought it might only return the first pilot name only if there were a pilot and co-pilot who's index was above 500, but if I have one booking for the day and both pilots above 500 it returns them both, so success!

Thanks to anyone who had a look and gave it some thought, even if they did not post anything or come up with a solution.

cheers

Braedon